# Putting signatures to Word documents

Tags: document-library, digital-signature

Is it possible to put signatures (simple texts) to the Word documents before the user starts downloading the file?

Thanks.

Comment: Why didn't you put signatures when the user uploads document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a custom solution to manipulate the OpenXML (assuming 2007+ format).

There is an older MSDN blog post that details the following:

- Reading the document into a byte array using the SPFile.OpenBinary
  method.
- Creating a resizable MemoryStream object using the parameterless
  constructor of the MemoryStream class.
- Writing the byte array into the MemoryStream.
- Opening the document using the Open XML SDK.  Trap the
  System.IO.FileFormatException when opening.
- Modifying the document using LINQ to XML and the Open XML SDK.
- Writing the document back to the document library.

Post is available here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/12/12/modifying-open-xml-documents-using-the-sharepoint-object-model.aspx

You cant really control all the download methods, so you will want to capture it on upload to make your changes.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to utilize Information Rights Management to add labels to your Word documents when opened.